# error: /Users/expo/workingdir/build/ios/PROEJCTNAME/main.jsbundle: No such file or directory (in target 'PROEJCTNAME' from project 'PROEJCTNAME')

Tags: react-native, expo, eas

In my expo project, im running the following commands:
`npx expo prebuild --platform ios`
`react-native bundle --entry-file='index.js' --bundle-output='./ios/TrendsAI/main.jsbundle' --dev=false --platform='ios'`

Then I add it to Build Phases -> Copy Bundle Resources.
(If I don't run react-native bundle and add it to bundle resources, the same error occurs)

Then I run
`eas build --profile production --platform ios`.

I get the following error

`Executing TrendsAI » [CP] Check Pods Manifest.lock
Tue, 28 Nov 2023 04:14:28 GMT

› Executing TrendsAI » Start Packager on http://localhost:8081
Tue, 28 Nov 2023 04:14:29 GMT

› Executing TrendsAI » [Expo] Configure project
Tue, 28 Nov 2023 04:14:30 GMT

› Copying   ./main.jsbundle ➜ ../../../Users/expo/workingdir/build/ios/TrendsAI/main.jsbundle
Tue, 28 Nov 2023 04:14:30 GMT

❌  error: /Users/expo/workingdir/build/ios/TrendsAI/main.jsbundle: No such file or directory (in target 'TrendsAI' from project 'TrendsAI')
`

Could somebody help?

I tried doing react-native bundle but it had the same error.
I deleted the ios folder and ran `eas build --profile production --platform ios` but it still failed with the same error.

Run fastlane should not have this error when I run eas build.

Comment: execute the following command in your terminal `cd ios && pod install && cd ..` and try to build again.